# Information/Applications of a homogeneous Monge-Ampere equation

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, applications

Does anyone know of any information/applications of the the quasilinear Monge-Ampere equation, $$u_{xx} - u_y u_{xy} + u_x u_{yy} = 0?$$ It appears in Forsyth's *Theory of Differential Equations* (vol. 6, p. 342), but he doesn't provide any background on the equation.

Comment: It is used to solve the [Weyl and Minkowski problems](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lfR-dhTZIcQJ:https://www.math.mcgill.ca/guan/Harvard-nonlinear%2520equations.pdf&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) in classical differential geometry